# Get the height of the next or previous hidden element to set height of the parent element. jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, hidden

I have a `ul` which contains images which are hidden and then loaded into a carousel using absolute positioning.

The height of these images is constrained in desktop view so I can control the height of the parent element as there is a small toggle menu below the `ul`.

When I switch to mobile I am using media queries to set the width of the image to 100% and reset the height. This means that the position of my toggle menu has to be calculated each time the next or previous slide is swiped as the image heights vary.

I currently have a function which is returning the height of the current slide and using that to set the height of the element, however I need this function to calculate the height of the next image if the user swipes right, or the previous for left.

This is my code:

```
// check height of slider 
var chSliderHeight = function(){ 
    var slider          = $('.slider');
    var sliderImg       = slider.find('li:visible img');
    var sliderImgNext   = sliderImg.parent().next().find('img').height();
    var sliderImgPrev   = sliderImg.parent().prev().find('img').height();
    var sliderH         = sliderImg.get(0).height;
    slider.css('height',sliderH + 40);
    console.log(sliderH, sliderImgNext, sliderImgPrev);
};

$(window).on('load resize orientationchange',function(){
    chSliderHeight();
});
```

The variables `sliderImgNext` and `sliderImgPrev` look like they are returning the values of the previous or next slides, but I don't know how to trigger the css height rule inside the swipe function.

And before this I have my swipe functions:

```
images.wipetouch({
    wipeLeft: function(result) { 
        target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
        if ( target === lastElem ) { target = 0; }
        else { target = target+1; }
        sliderResponseMobile(target);
        chSliderHeight();
    },
    wipeRight: function() {
        target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
        lastElem = triggers.length-1;
        if ( target === 0 ) { target = lastElem; }
        else { target = target-1; }
        sliderResponseMobile(target);
        chSliderHeight();
    }
});
```

I need some condition to run a slightly different function or parameter if swiping left or right. Maybe this should run inside a success function, I am not 100% sure. Maybe hoisting?

I am finding it difficult to get around the issue of writing a function inside `chSliderHeight` which is available to `wipeLeft` and `wipeRight` functions.

I have a full fiddle with a single dependency (and all other code loaded) [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/bpy2e5jv/)

This also has all the other code and vars contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK managed to get this working.

One issue I was having, because the slider uses a fadeIn/fadeOut function, calling `slider.find('li:visible img');` is returning a length of 2 as there are two slides visible at the time of calling the function.

So I changed my selector to this:

```
slider.find('li[class="active"] img');
```

And the length is now 1.

I then wrote a callback function like this:

```
var callback = function(){
    var slider          = $('.slider');
    var sliderImg       = slider.find('li[class="active"] img');
    var sliderH         = sliderImg.get(0).height;
    slider.css('height',sliderH + 40);
};
```

And passed the callback function into the wipetouch functions, like so:

```
images.wipetouch({
        wipeLeft: function(result) { 
            target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
            if ( target === lastElem ) { target = 0; }
            else { target = target+1; }
            sliderResponseMobile(target);
            callback();
        },
        wipeRight: function() {
            target = $('ul.triggers li.selected').index();
            lastElem = triggers.length-1;
            if ( target === 0 ) { target = lastElem; }
            else { target = target-1; }
            sliderResponseMobile(target);
            callback();
        }
    });
```

`sliderResponseMobile(target);` now looks like this (so it adds an active class to each slide):

```
function sliderResponseMobile(target) {
        images.removeClass('active').fadeOut(200).eq(target).fadeIn(400).addClass('active');
    }
```

And here is a working [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/u399oprz/3/)